# Форма обратной связи

Tags: java, jsp, форма

У меня есть страница HTML, в которой написана форма обратной связи.

Проверку заполнения формы на JavaScript я сделаю, а что дальше - от нажатия кнопки «отправить» и до получения письма на e-mail?

Требуется сделать обработку формы (серверную часть) без PHP, а с использованием JSP, сервлетов, а также капчу без PHP. В этом я полный "0". Если есть материал (можно видео) по работе сервера, как обрабатывается форма, куда вставляется код, в мельчайших подробностях - буду очень рад получить, или подскажите где найти.

Answer (score 2):

Отбрасывая все детали, создаете разметку страницы:

```html
<form action="someservlet" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="address" value="${param.address}"
         ${not empty messages.succes ? 'disabled' : ''}>
  <p class="error">${messages.address}</p>
  <input type="submit">
  <p class="succes">${messages.succes}</p>
</form>
```

и добавляете обработку

```java
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
  Map<String, String> messages = new HashMap<String, String>();
  request.setAttribute("messages", messages);

  String address = request.getParameter("address");

  if (address == null || address.trim().isEmpty()) {
    messages.put("address", "Пожалуйста, заполните поле");
  }

  if (messages.isEmpty()) {
    // Сформировать текст сообщения и отправить на почту        
    messages.put("succes", "Сообщение успешно отослано");
  }

  request.getRequestDispatcher("somepage.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

Еще вам потребуется [капча](http://code.google.com/p/kaptcha/) и сам [API почты](http://commons.apache.org/email/). Про JSP почитать хотя бы здесь: [JSP](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSP). :)